# Лишние символы в html-разметке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

На странице внезапно появились символы `` c разными вариациями, в зависимости от ОС:

- Вид в Windows:
  [image: вид из windows]
- Вид в Linux:
  [image: вид из linux]

С чем это связанно?
Как этого впредь избегать?

Comment: html ваш покажите

Comment: @dimensi  '60+ '
вопрос в том, почему и как они туда попали? 
Может шрифты из  cdn обновились ?

Comment: Вообще это значит, что у вас используется символ которого нет на сайте. Проверьте иконки или что там у вас

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в `head` тег `<meta charset="utf-8">`. В CSS продублируйте строку `@charset "UTF-8";` в самое начало файла стилей.